# Matrix stored in a std::vector

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

Let's suppose I have a square matrix (e.g. 4x4):

```
a_00 a_01 a_02 a_03
a_10 a_11 a_12 a_13
a_20 a_21 a_22 a_23
a_30 a_31 a_32 a_33
```

And assume I stored this matrix in a C++ std::vector v, **without the entries on the main diagonal** (a_ij where i=j):

```
v = {a_01, a_02, a_03, a_10, a_12, a_13, a_20, a_21, a_23, a_30, a_31, a_32}
```

How can I write a C++ function `int idx(int i, int j)` that returns the index of the entry a_ij in vector v?

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: I didn't found a solution yet!

Comment: Then please try something , so people here can help you knowing that you put effort into it.

Comment: Obviously without this main diagonal constraint I would return i*num_rows+j. I was thinking about a rule to skip the i=j case with an if clause.

Comment: `without the entries on the main diagonal` What does this mean? Is the entry 0 at `i==j`? What does the function return if `i==j`?

Comment: Also `returns the index of the entry a_ij` You're passing the indices. Do you want to return the entry at `a[i][j]`? I'm so confused.

Comment: What if `i == j` in your function?

Answer (score 0):

## include

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, n;
    cin >> n >> i >> j;
    int ans = i * n + j - i;
    if (j > i)
        ans--;
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I do this. I solve the problem with actually thinking that we have the main diagonal. Then the answer would be i * n + j. It's obvious that in each row there's only one entry on the main diagonal so we subtract the number of rows before the i-th row, which is i.

Now we have to use an if statement to see if the entry on main diagonal of the i-th row is before or after the j-th element. Really simple.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, instead of i * n_cols + j you only need to multiply by (n_cols-1) - as you are missing one item in each row. Also, you need to adjust j as well (basically: `if (j > i) --j` ). And return error if i == j.